# Porting iPhone PhoneGap app to Android - Scaling Issue

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, scaling

I'm working on porting an iOS app built with PhoneGap 2.2.0 to Android. My main issue is having the app scale appropriately depending on the device's screen size. Using `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`, I get this info about my Android device:

```
DisplayMetrics{
    density=1.5, 
    width=540, 
    height=960, 
    scaledDensity=1.2750001, 
    xdpi=368.06036, 
    ydpi=365.22525
}
```

This is my viewport:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, 
minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=143" />`

As you can see I am hardcoding the `target-densitydpi` to get the app to reasonably scale to  fit the screen of my Android device. Since I want my app to support multiple screens, is there a way to use the information given by `DisplayMetrics` to adjust the `viewport` appropriately.

I have looked up different solutions online but none seems to work as expected to.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the problem from a different angle: how can I make my application scale to the screen size of any device? At this point you are trying to support Android and iOS, but later on you might also want to support tablets, Windows Phone 8, BB devices, etc. As such, I would go with a web application design that is responsive to the screen dimensions: that is the application dynamically allocates space according to available dimensions. Check out the below links/frameworks for responsive design:

- [Twitter Bootstrap: Responsive Scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)
- [WebBlocks: Responsive Mobile Designs](https://github.com/ucla/mwf/wiki/WebBlocks)

You can also read more about the reasons behind the technology at: [Why 2013 is the Year of Responsive Web Design?](http://mashable.com/2012/12/11/responsive-web-design/)